# Sort and display an Array of Objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, drop-down-menu

I have created a function to dislpay the objects in an Array.

```
let shownObjects = myArray;
function showTheObjects(displayedObjects) {
    document.getElementByID('divToDisplayObjects').innerHTML = "";
    for (let i of shownObjects) {
        // Code to display the objects
    }
}
```

This code works as expected.

I have also created a Select Tag in HTML containing different sort options.

I have created a function to sort the objects based upon the option selected.

```
let sortButton = document.getElementById('selectID');
function changeSortOfObjects() {
    let sortOption = sortButton.value;
    if (sortOption === "option-1") {shownObjects.sort(Sort By Name)}
    else if (sortOption === "option-2") {shownObjects.sort(Sort By Age)}
    showTheObjects(shownObjects)

}
sortButton.onchange = changeSortOfObjects;
changeSortOfObjects();
```

When I click on a select option, all of the objects disappear from the screen, instead of reordering. What is the issue which is causing the objects to dissappear instead of reordering?

I have looked at multiple different questions on Stack Overflow but cannot find any answers to my problem. I have also looked online for different videos and articles but cannot find an answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by the showTheObjects function, specifically the line `document.getElementByID('divToDisplayObjects').innerHTML = "";.` This line clears the contents of the HTML element with the ID divToDisplayObjects every time the showTheObjects function is called. This means that when the changeSortOfObjects function is called and the shownObjects array is sorted, the showTheObjects function is called again with the sorted array, but first, it clears the contents of divToDisplayObjects, causing the objects to disappear from the screen.

To fix this issue, you can modify the showTheObjects function to only add to the contents of the HTML element instead of clearing it. You can do this by changing the line `document.getElementByID('divToDisplayObjects').innerHTML = "";` to `let displayDiv = document.getElementByID('divToDisplayObjects');` and then modifying the line in the for loop that displays the objects to `displayDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + i + "</p>";.`

This will append each object to the contents of the HTML element instead of replacing it.

Here's the modified showTheObjects function:

```
function showTheObjects(displayedObjects) {
    let displayDiv = document.getElementByID('divToDisplayObjects');
    displayDiv.innerHTML = "";
    for (let i of shownObjects) {
        displayDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
    }
}
```

With this modification, the objects should not disappear when the changeSortOfObjects function is called to sort the shownObjects array.